# how to disable scroll in multiline edittext

Tags: android, xml

I have an EditText, and some more views inside a Scrollview. The EditText is set to multiline, and does not have a max height. So the EditText can increase its height based on the content that is being entered in it.
I want the parent scroll view to scroll when I try to scroll through the EditText content

I have tried the code from this https://gist.github.com/RobertZagorski/409b91e2d2cb279f827c202b9de092f4
and also tried

> editText.setMovementMethod(null);

Here is the full code

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/postLinearContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroupPostType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/postEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.25"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want to achieve something the the Gmail App compose, where in the whole screen is scrolled when Composed Message is scrolled

[image: This is how i want it to work]

Comment: did you try remove `android:isScrollContainer="true"` or set `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Use NestedScrollView, That will solve your entire problem.

[NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView)